# Omniauth-facebook & Devise: if email exists

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, email-validation

I'm using omniauth-facebook and devise for authentication in my rails 4 app.
I would like for a user, that already has authenticated through devise, also be able to add facebook auth later if they choose.
I would like to figure out how to check if the email of the devise logged user matches that of a facebook user, and if yes, add the uid and provider to that registered user.

Currently, I am getting the devise error message: "**Email has already been taken**"

User.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.username = auth.info.username
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)      
  end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    #render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      #session[:user_id] = user.id # for current_user
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :facebook, :all
end
```

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 18):

I just had the same problem and used this code to solve it.

It first checks if the email exists in the database and if it does it updates the ***uid*** and the ***provider*** fields, if not I create a new user with the auth params. In the end I just return the variable ***return_user*** and the flow works as normal.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  if self.where(email: auth.info.email).exists?
    return_user = self.where(email: auth.info.email).first
    return_user.provider = auth.provider
    return_user.uid = auth.uid
  else
    return_user = self.create do |user|
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.name = auth.info.name
       user.username = auth.info.username
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
       user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at) 
    end
  end

  return_user
end
```